# Python Text to Speech in Macintosh

Tags: python, macos, text-to-speech

Are there any libraries in Python that does or allows  Text To Speech Conversion using Mac Lion's built in text to speech engine?
I did google but most are windows based. I tried pyttx.
I tried to run

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Sally sells seashells by the seashore.')
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

But I get these errors

```
File "/Users/manabchetia/Documents/Codes/Speech.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx-1.0.egg/pyttsx/__init__.py", line 39, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx-1.0.egg/pyttsx/engine.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx-1.0.egg/pyttsx/driver.py", line 64, in __init__
    self._module = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx-1.0.egg/pyttsx/drivers/nsss.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Foundation
```

How do I solve these errors?

Comment: Surely you can just use the OSX `say` command?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I did google and tried pyttx but i get errors.

Comment: @ManabChetia: That is a material difference, now you have a practical question! :-)

Comment: `Foundation` is part of the [`pyobjc` library](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/); did you install it? It comes by default with the *system* python, but I see you installed your own Python 2.7.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have not installed it. So I need to type in `easy_install pyobjc` now?

Comment: @ManabChetia: Yup, looks like it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Still Same errors.

Comment: @ManabChetia: Then you didn't install PyObjC into the *right* python installation. Double-check what python is used when you run `easy_install`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I get these `pyobjc 2.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth`. Please help.

Comment: @ManabChetia: Check the python path of `easy_install`: `head \`which easy_install\``

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Wouldn't it be much simpler to do this?

```
from os import system
system('say Hello world!')
```

You can enter `man say` to see other things you can do with the `say` command.

However, if you want some more advanced features, importing `AppKit` would also be a possibility, although some Cocoa/Objective C knowledge is needed.

```
from AppKit import NSSpeechSynthesizer
speechSynthesizer = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_("com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Bruce")
speechSynthesizer.startSpeakingString_('Hi! Nice to meet you!')
```

If you would like to see more things you can do with NSSpeechSynthesizer take a look at Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: if hello world is in a variable how do i make `say` speak it? I tried AppKit but it's not available. `easy_install' was not able to do it either. how do i do that?

Comment: If you want to pass a variable to the say command, you could do this:
str = "Test"
system('say %s' % (str))

Comment: The code snippet in this answer is slightly off. ``.alloc`` is a function, so it should be ``.alloc()``

Comment: Including an apostrophe in the string may cause this to not work. For example trying to do `system("Can't touch this")` will run without an error, but not actually say anything out loud.

Comment: @ProQ normal shell quoting rules apply of course. You could embed that string in literal quotes for example (like you would normally have to)

Comment: So then doing `system('say "{}"'.format(words))` seems to be the way to go

Comment: Another odd thing about the `system` option is that it doesn't appear to work with bluetooth headphones. YouTube plays just fine, but I hear nothing when running this command. If I turn off bluetooth, I hear it just fine.

Comment: Does that also happen if you change the default audio source? I'm not behind a Mac rn, but maybe there is option within say to change it.

Answer (score 13):

If you are targeting Mac OS X as your platform - PyObjC and NSSpeechSynthesizer is your best bet.

Here is a quick example for you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from  AppKit import NSSpeechSynthesizer
import time
import sys


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   text = raw_input('type text to speak> ')
else:
   text = sys.argv[1]

nssp = NSSpeechSynthesizer

ve = nssp.alloc().init()

for voice in nssp.availableVoices():
   ve.setVoice_(voice)
   print voice
   ve.startSpeakingString_(text)

   while not ve.isSpeaking():
      time.sleep(0.1)

   while ve.isSpeaking():
      time.sleep(0.1)
```

Please note that AppKit module is part of PyObjC bridge and should be already installed on your Mac. No need to install it if you are using OS provided python (/usr/bin/python)

Comment: For more detail on how to use the Cocoa Speech Synthesizer interface (e.g. what does setRate_'s argument mean?), have a look at Apple's Developer documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["say","Hello World! (MESSAGE)"])
```