# how to use speech-recognition of mac from within python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, speech-recognition

There is this awesome threat, showing how to use the say-command from mac within python:
[Python Text to Speech in Macintosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758591/python-text-to-speech-in-macintosh)

Is there anything similar for the speech-recognition?
I would like to use the german speech-recognition from mac to get a user-input.

Other possible answer for this question would be a speech-recognition within python for german-languages.

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work and the SpeechRecognition package will handle German

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
   audio = r.listen(source)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Unfortunately it does not work for me in this way. I do get the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SpeechRecognition as sr
ImportError: No module named SpeechRecognition

The library is installed and the minimal-example works fine. Why would it work in german? How to you tell pyhton to change language?

Comment: Incredibly sorry I had the package name wrong, thats my bad. It should work now. And SpeechRecognition supports like 188 different languages. Check it out here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: sorry, but one question left: How do i change to german language? Do i have to install the language-package for pocketsquinx for example? Is there an easy way, maybe via pip?

Comment: No problem at all. You o have to install pocket-sphinx, but from that point on you just specify the language you want to use.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but i don't get this running. When downloading the official language-pack and run the sh, I do get following error-message:
ERROR: "pocketsphinx.c", line 134: Failed to find mdef file inside the model folder specified with -hmm 'model_parameters/voxforge.cd_cont_4000'
INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
ERROR: "acmod.c", line 87: Folder 'model_parameters/voxforge.cd_cont_4000' does not contain acoustic model definition 'mdef'

Comment: Pocketsphinx does not support German well, you'd better use Google backend

Answer (score 1):

Great! Thanks for your help. To use google with german, simply add language="de"

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio, language="de"))
```